# StringTokenizer and String split - split on special character

Tags: java, string, split, stringtokenizer

I have the string:

> 2|HOME ELECTRONICS| |0|0| | | | |0| |

I want to separate all tokens delimited by `|` in the above string.

I tried to tokenize it with `StringTokenizer` but it doesn't consider space as a token.

Also, I tried `split("|")` but it gives each character of the above string as elements in returned string array.

What should I do?

Comment: "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead. " and do accept the answer that helped you...

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
string.split("\\|");
```

`|` is a special character and must be espaced with escape character `\`. In Java `\` is written as `\\`.

That is because [String#split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes *regular expression* as a parameter.

In a *regex* special chars like `.`, `|`, `(`, etc must be escaped. Otherwise, Java will think you are actually using the special char (for example the `|` means *OR*).

Comment: Another way would be `string.split("[|]")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Scanner instead of StringTokenizer

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(str);
    sc.useDelimiter("\\|");
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        String e = sc.next();
    }
```