# How to get an array of strings by separating the symbol '|'?

Tags: java

String "aaaaaaaa|bbbbbbbbb|cccccccc|dddddddddd|"

There is code

```
 for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
        mas[i]=str.substring(i,str.indexOf("|",i) );
 }
```

How to get an array of strings by separating the symbol '|'?

SORRY, HOW to ADD CODE in Comment? in StackOverlow?

Comment: is this for Java or C++ ? Please remove the tag that doesn't apply.

Comment: read [Markdown Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148150/stringtokenizer-and-string-split-split-on-special-character

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a String in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: @BiscuitBaker, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148150/stringtokenizer-and-string-split-split-on-special-character.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java Not Duplicate!

Comment: SORRY for DUplicate, I just learned how to use the site , do not judge strictly !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using String's [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method like:

```
String str = "aaaaaaaa|bbbbbbbbb|cccccccc|dddddddddd";
String[] mas=str.split("\\|");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mas));
Output:
[aaaaaaaa, bbbbbbbbb, cccccccc, dddddddddd]
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java:

```
String myString = "asdasda|asdasdadasda|dfsfsdff|sdfsdfsdfsfd|";
String[] arrayOfStrings = myString.split("\\|");
```

Comment: you need \\ to split with special chars

Comment: not working((

        String myString = "asdasda|asdasdadasda|dfsfsdff|sdfsdfsdfsfd|";
        String[] arrayOfStrings = myString.split("|");

        for (String asd: arrayOfStrings){
            Log.e("asdasd",asd);
        }
    }

Comment: Thanks Cataclysm. I could have sworn I used it a few days ago like that. But I checked it and you're correct. Serves me right for not testing first :P.

Comment: frodopusto: as Cataclysm and SMA indicated, I needed to add \\ before the |. This is because split in java expects a regular expression (and | is a special character).